# Obtener Value de un Select en PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estoy enviando un mail por un formulario en php y todo funciona correctamente, el problema es que el valor que selecciona el usuario en un **select** HTML me envia es el **id** de la base de datos que tengo creada, más no el nombre del elemento.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito mostrar el nombre del **select**, ejemplo: **País**: Colombia, **Estado**: Antioquia, **Ciudad**: Medellín

Este es mi php:

```html
<?php
    if(!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $Destino = "correo@gmail.com";
        $Nombres = $_REQUEST['Nombres'];
        $Email = $_REQUEST['Email'];
        $Telefono = $_REQUEST['Telefono'];
        $Pais = $_REQUEST(['country']);
        $Estado = $_REQUEST['state'];
        $Ciudad = $_REQUEST['city'];
        $Mensaje = $_REQUEST['mensaje'];
        $titulo = "Mensaje enviado Página Web | Formulario de contacto.";
        $Contenido = "Nombres y apellidos: " . $Nombres . "\nCorreo electrónico: " . $Email . "\nTeléfono: " . $Telefono . "\nPaís:" . $Pais . "\nEstado:" . $Estado . "\nCiudad:" . $Ciudad . "\nMensaje:" . $Mensaje;
        $envio = mail($Destino, $titulo, $Contenido);
        echo ($envio) ? 'success' : 'error';
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('Ocurrio un error inesperado intente de nuevo más tarde');</script>";
    }
?>
```

Obtengo el value de los demás por medio del **name**

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="md-form">
                        <select name="country" id="country" class="mdb-select md-form" searchable="Search here..">
                            <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione País</option>
                                <?php
                                    if($rowCount > 0){
                                        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
                                            echo '<option value="'.$row['country_id'].'">'.$row['country_name'].'</option>';
                                        }
                                    }else{
                                        echo '<option value="">Ciudad no disponible</option>';
                                    }
                                ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label for="state">Estado</label>
                    <select name="state" id="state" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Seleccione país primero</option> 
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label for="city">Ciudad</label>
                    <select name="city" id="city" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Selecione estado primero</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

Cualquier aporte es valido

Answer (score 0):

Si en php no haras ningún tipo de validación puedes enviar el dato desde el select

```
echo '<option value="'.$row['country_name'].'">'.$row['country_name'].'</option>';
```

Por otra parte, te sugiero hagas una minima validación de si el dato enviado existe o no y utilizae GET y POST

```
$Pais = isset($_POST['country']) ? $_POST['country'] : '';
// Si tu versión de php es reciente puedes usarlo asi
$Pais = $_POST['country'] ?? '';
```

Comment: Y como le envió el dato a la variable, para que no llegue el id de la base de datos

Comment: Justo como te dije, en el value del option colocas el nombre y no el id

Comment: Pero yo cargo esos datos desde una Base de Datos Mysql, por me pinta el ID, lo intente y me sigue mandando el Id